# Sparklyr taking too long between jobs

Tags: r, apache-spark

I'm having an issue with spark executing jobs, that is, between a filter and the spark_write_csv function , the elapsed time is around 14 minutes. I have already reinstalled java, spark and hadoop, all with no effect. Besides, recently I had to reinstall my current OS(windows) on a ssd, it seems to me that after that this "error" appeared. My code is structured as follows.

```
conf <- spark_config()
conf$spark.serializer <- "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
conf$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "20G"
conf$spark.memory.fraction <- 0.6
conf$spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled <-'false'
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local",config = conf)

df <- spark_read_csv(sc = sc,name='mark1',
                        path=path_to_file,
                        columns = columns_name,
                        infer_schema = FALSE,
                        delimiter = ";",header = TRUE,
                        overwrite = TRUE,memory=T,repartition=5)

df %>% dplyr::filter(ids %in% id_list) %>%
    dplyr::select(columns_to_select) %>%
      spark_write_csv(x=.,path=partions_save_folder,mode='overwrite')
```

The id_list is a list containing 1.8M ids, and the file I'm looking into is small, 10GB.

My spark version is 3.1.1 and hadoop 3.2

And my enviroment is:

```
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.6     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.4.0     tidyr_1.1.3     tibble_3.1.1    ggplot2_3.3.3   tidyverse_1.3.1 sparklyr_1.6.2 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        lubridate_1.7.10  forge_0.2.0       prettyunits_1.1.1 ps_1.6.0          assertthat_0.2.1  rprojroot_2.0.2   digest_0.6.27     utf8_1.2.1       
[10] R6_2.5.0          cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.2.1   reprex_2.0.0      httr_1.4.2        pillar_1.6.0      rlang_0.4.11      readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.13  
[19] callr_3.7.0       desc_1.3.0        config_0.3.1      devtools_2.4.1    r2d3_0.2.5        htmlwidgets_1.5.3 munsell_0.5.0     broom_0.7.6       compiler_4.0.5   
[28] modelr_0.1.8      pkgconfig_2.0.3   base64enc_0.1-3   pkgbuild_1.2.0    htmltools_0.5.1.1 tidyselect_1.1.1  fansi_0.4.2       crayon_1.4.1      dbplyr_2.1.1     
[37] withr_2.4.2       grid_4.0.5        jsonlite_1.7.2    gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_1.0.0   DBI_1.1.1         magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      writexl_1.4.0    
[46] cli_2.5.0         stringi_1.6.1     cachem_1.0.4      remotes_2.3.0     fs_1.5.0          testthat_3.0.2    xml2_1.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.2    generics_0.1.0   
[55] vctrs_0.3.8       tools_4.0.5       glue_1.4.2        hms_1.0.0         pkgload_1.2.1     processx_3.5.2    parallel_4.0.5    fastmap_1.1.0     yaml_2.2.1
```